# entity framework - inheritance design

Tags: entity-framework

Using .Net 4 with EF 1.0: I have a table per type inheritance database structure and edmx (see diagram and cutdown edmx at the end of the post.  The edmx is created through a code generator).  I've just included one subtype for this post but there are many!

All of our entity framework queries are also dynamically generated.  So at the moment when I try to retrieve a product (which may or may not be a book) I have the following ESQL query being generated.

```
SELECT VALUE [tb_product] FROM [tb_product] as [tb_product] WHERE (([tb_product].[Id] = @p0))
```

If the object I've requested is a book, the object I'm getting returned to me is of type 'tb_product'.  I can't seem to cast or otherwise access the 'book' information from this tb_product object.

How can I modify the query, edmx or some other component so that when I query the base type I can also access all relevant subtype information without a second database trip.  Can I?

[image]

```
  <edmx:Runtime>
<!-- SSDL content -->
<edmx:StorageModels>
  <Schema Namespace="MyModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2005" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm/ssdl">
    <EntityContainer Name="MyModelStoreContainer">       
      <EntitySet Name="tb_productBook" EntityType="MyModel.Store.tb_productBook" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />      
      <EntitySet Name="tb_product" EntityType="MyModel.Store.tb_product" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />               
      <AssociationSet Name="FK_IdProductBook_Product" Association="MyModel.Store.FK_IdProductBook_Product">
        <End Role="tb_product" EntitySet="tb_product" />
        <End Role="tb_productBook" EntitySet="tb_productBook" />
      </AssociationSet>        
    </EntityContainer>   
    <EntityType Name="tb_productBook">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="id" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="id" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="title" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="150" />
      <Property Name="subtitle" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="150" />
      <Property Name="length" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="productCoverTypeId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="volumeEdition" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="15" />
      <Property Name="publisherName" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100" />
      <Property Name="publishDate" Type="datetime" />
      <Property Name="iSBNNumber" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="30" />
      <Property Name="description" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="authorBio" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="audience" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="expireDate" Type="datetime" />
      <Property Name="vendorId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="productCommissionTypeId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="commissionValue" Type="decimal" Nullable="false" Precision="9" Scale="2" />
      <Property Name="languageId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="countryId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="stateId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="inventoryLocation" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="2000" />
    </EntityType>     
    <EntityType Name="tb_product">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="id" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="id" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
      <Property Name="name" Type="varchar" MaxLength="100" />
      <Property Name="productSku" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="17" />
      <Property Name="productTypeId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="price" Type="decimal" Nullable="false" Precision="9" Scale="2" />
      <Property Name="marketOnWeb" Type="bit" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="subsidiaryId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="lmsProductId" Type="int" />
      <Property Name="topicId" Type="int" />
      <Property Name="categoryId" Type="int" />
      <Property Name="eventId" Type="int" />
      <Property Name="note" Type="varchar" />
      <Property Name="expirationDate" Type="datetime" />
      <Property Name="mediaLength" Type="int" />
      <Property Name="urlSlug" Type="varchar" MaxLength="200" />
      <Property Name="productSourceId" Type="int" />
      <Property Name="created" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="createdBy" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="30" />
      <Property Name="lastUpdated" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="lastUpdatedBy" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="30" />
    </EntityType>        
    <Association Name="FK_IdProductBook_Product">
      <End Role="tb_product" Type="MyModel.Store.tb_product" Multiplicity="1">
        <OnDelete Action="Cascade" />
      </End>
      <End Role="tb_productBook" Type="MyModel.Store.tb_productBook" Multiplicity="0..1" />
      <ReferentialConstraint>
        <Principal Role="tb_product">
          <PropertyRef Name="id" />
        </Principal>
        <Dependent Role="tb_productBook">
          <PropertyRef Name="id" />
        </Dependent>
      </ReferentialConstraint>
    </Association>
  </Schema>
</edmx:StorageModels>
<!-- CSDL content -->
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
  <Schema Namespace="MyModel" Alias="Self" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm">
    <EntityContainer Name="MyEntities">
      <EntitySet Name="tb_product" EntityType="MyModel.tb_product" />                 
    </EntityContainer>        
    <EntityType Name="tb_productBook" BaseType="MyModel.tb_product">
      <Property Name="title" Type="String" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="subtitle" Type="String" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="length" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="volumeEdition" Type="String" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="publisherName" Type="String" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="publishDate" Type="DateTime" Nullable="true" />
      <Property Name="iSBNNumber" Type="String" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="description" Type="String" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="authorBio" Type="String" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="audience" Type="String" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="expireDate" Type="DateTime" Nullable="true" />
      <Property Name="vendorId" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="commissionValue" Type="Decimal" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="inventoryLocation" Type="String" Nullable="false" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="ProductBook_Country" Relationship="MyModel.FK_CountryProductBook_Country" FromRole="tb_productBook" ToRole="tb_country" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="ProductBook_Language" Relationship="MyModel.FK_LanguageProductBook_Language" FromRole="tb_productBook" ToRole="tb_language" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="ProductBook_ProductCommissionType" Relationship="MyModel.FK_ProductCommissionTypeProductBook_ProductCommissionType" FromRole="tb_productBook" ToRole="tb_productCommissionType" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="ProductBook_ProductCoverType" Relationship="MyModel.FK_ProductCoverTypeProductBook_ProductCoverType" FromRole="tb_productBook" ToRole="tb_productCoverType" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="ProductBook_State" Relationship="MyModel.FK_StateProductBook_State" FromRole="tb_productBook" ToRole="tb_state" />
    </EntityType>    
    <EntityType Name="tb_product">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="id" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="id" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="name" Type="String" Nullable="true" />
      <Property Name="productSku" Type="String" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="price" Type="Decimal" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="marketOnWeb" Type="Boolean" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="subsidiaryId" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="lmsProductId" Type="Int32" Nullable="true" />
      <Property Name="topicId" Type="Int32" Nullable="true" />
      <Property Name="note" Type="String" Nullable="true" />
      <Property Name="expirationDate" Type="DateTime" Nullable="true" />
      <Property Name="mediaLength" Type="Int32" Nullable="true" />
      <Property Name="urlSlug" Type="String" Nullable="true" />
      <Property Name="created" Type="DateTime" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="createdBy" Type="String" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="lastUpdated" Type="DateTime" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="lastUpdatedBy" Type="String" Nullable="false" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="CampaignAdvertisedProduct_Product" Relationship="MyModel.FK_ProductCampaignAdvertisedProduct_Product" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_campaignAdvertisedProduct" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="DiscountGroupProduct_Product" Relationship="MyModel.FK_ProductDiscountGroupProduct_Product" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_discountGroupProduct" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="LogCampaignResponseUpdate_Product" Relationship="MyModel.FK_ProductLogCampaignResponseUpdate_Product" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_logCampaignResponseUpdate" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="ProductAuthor_Product" Relationship="MyModel.FK_ProductProductAuthor_Product" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_productAuthor" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="ProductImage_Product" Relationship="MyModel.FK_ProductProductImage_Product" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_productImage" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="ProductMarketingContent_Product" Relationship="MyModel.FK_ProductProductMarketingContent_Product" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_productMarketingContent" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="ProductOnsiteStaffAgency_Product" Relationship="MyModel.FK_ProductProductOnsiteStaffAgency_Product" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_productOnsiteStaffAgency" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="ProductProblem_Product" Relationship="MyModel.FK_ProductProductProblem_Product" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_productProblem" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="ProductVenue_Product" Relationship="MyModel.FK_ProductProductVenue_Product" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_productVenue" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="VenueEmailRequest_Product" Relationship="MyModel.FK_ProductVenueEmailRequest_Product" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_venueEmailRequest" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="Product_Category" Relationship="MyModel.FK_CategoryProduct_Category" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_category" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="Product_ProductSource" Relationship="MyModel.FK_ProductSourceProduct_ProductSource" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_productSource" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="Product_ProductType" Relationship="MyModel.FK_ProductTypeProduct_ProductType" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_productType" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="Product_Event" Relationship="MyModel.FK_EventProduct_Event" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_event" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="tb_category" Relationship="MyModel.tb_product_category" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_category" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="tb_contact" Relationship="MyModel.tb_product_faculty" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_contact" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="tb_state" Relationship="MyModel.tb_product_State" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_state" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="tb_vendorCost" Relationship="MyModel.tb_product_VendorCost" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_vendorCost" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="tb_vendorInvoice" Relationship="MyModel.tb_product_VendorInvoice" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_vendorInvoice" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="tb_vendorPayment" Relationship="MyModel.tb_product_VendorPayment" FromRole="tb_product" ToRole="tb_vendorPayment" />
    </EntityType>     
  </Schema>
</edmx:ConceptualModels>
<!-- C-S mapping content -->
<edmx:Mappings>
  <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:windows:storage:mapping:CS">
    <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="MyModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="MyEntities">      
      <EntitySetMapping Name="tb_product">
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(MyModel.tb_product)">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="tb_product">
            <ScalarProperty Name="lastUpdatedBy" ColumnName="lastUpdatedBy" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="lastUpdated" ColumnName="lastUpdated" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="createdBy" ColumnName="createdBy" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="created" ColumnName="created" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="urlSlug" ColumnName="urlSlug" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="mediaLength" ColumnName="mediaLength" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="expirationDate" ColumnName="expirationDate" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="note" ColumnName="note" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="topicId" ColumnName="topicId" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="lmsProductId" ColumnName="lmsProductId" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="subsidiaryId" ColumnName="subsidiaryId" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="marketOnWeb" ColumnName="marketOnWeb" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="price" ColumnName="price" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="productSku" ColumnName="productSku" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="name" ColumnName="name" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="id" ColumnName="id" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>          
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(MyModel.tb_productBook)">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="tb_productBook">
            <ScalarProperty Name="inventoryLocation" ColumnName="inventoryLocation" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="commissionValue" ColumnName="commissionValue" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="vendorId" ColumnName="vendorId" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="expireDate" ColumnName="expireDate" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="audience" ColumnName="audience" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="authorBio" ColumnName="authorBio" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="description" ColumnName="description" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="iSBNNumber" ColumnName="iSBNNumber" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="publishDate" ColumnName="publishDate" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="publisherName" ColumnName="publisherName" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="volumeEdition" ColumnName="volumeEdition" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="length" ColumnName="length" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="subtitle" ColumnName="subtitle" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="title" ColumnName="title" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="id" ColumnName="id" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>            
      </EntitySetMapping>
    </EntityContainerMapping>
  </Mapping>
</edmx:Mappings>
```

Comment: Can you try to use `OFTYPE` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399295.aspx) for `ProductBook` in your Entity SQL query and see if it returns expected `ProductBook` entities?

Comment: reading the doco I don't think that is quite what I'm after.  I need to be able to get all products regardless of their subtype.  But once I have that collection of objects, I also want to be able to look at each individual object and get at the appropriate subtype info (when they have it - some products will only be of the base class type).

Comment: I understood that. My proposal was meant as a test if derived entities get loaded at all. If you had a correct TPT mapping your query should actually work as you want, i.e. it should materialize `ProductBook` instances when there is a `ProductBook` in the DB. To me the EDMX doesn't look *obviously* wrong but I'm not sure. Did you btw check in a sql profiler if the generated query looks correct? It should contain a JOIN between `Product` and `ProductBook` (and other derived) tables.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that - we do have logs of the actual SQL generated.  I will look in the morning.

Comment: Ugh, I am such a dill - checking the raw SQL confirms the query is retrieving all the data required.  I think I was just trying to cast the wrong object to tb_productBook.  When I corrected that - I am getting the result I expected.  Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: Cool, that was an easy solution :)